# Paypal Standards IPN ERROR

Tags: paypal

I'm having some problems with Paypal Standards. 
I was originally getting an error #40710 that my return URL was no good, so I disabled Auto return in paypal. 
Now I am getting this error: Sending a relative URL to PayPalIPN is erroneous. Please make your resource URL (in Administer » System Settings » Resource URLs ) complete.
I even disabled the IPN feature in paypal but still get the error and unable to make a donation through paypal.

How do I get Auto Return and IPN features working?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check your resource url setting? If so, what is it?

It needs to be a complete url, as explained in the help for that field:

http://mysite.mydomain.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/

Comment: The resource url was set at 
 http://mysite.mydomain.com/profiles/civicrm_starterkit/modules/civicrm.

 I tried to change it to http://mysite.mydomain.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/.

The problem still persists.

Comment: The URL needs to include http://.